# Can I get the numbers after the underscore?

Tags: python, database, dataframe, data-analysis

**Input values**

```
id  values
0   Q56_0.01 Q57_0.99
1   Q1_0.01 Q57_0.96 Q67_0.03
```

I need the output dataframe in the below format

**Output**

```
id  values
0   0.01 
0   0.99
1   0.01 
1   0.96 
1   0.03
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to explain your question with the code but as far as I understand answer of your question should be like that:
I used split function -> https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp

```
my_string="Q56_0.01"
print (my_string.split("_",1)[1])
```

Output : 0.01

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) dataframe, you can use [`str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) combnied with [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
(df
 .assign(values=df['values'].str.findall('_(\d+(?:\.\d+))'))
 .explode('values')
 .astype({'values': float})
)
```

output:

```
   id  values
0   0    0.01
0   0    0.99
1   1    0.01
1   1    0.96
1   1    0.03
```